# increment of plus 1 in textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sql-server-2012

```
public void MaxApointNo()
    {
        string db = "Data Source=DESKTOP-R6H3RTP; Initial Catalog=TokenDB; Integrated Security=true; ";
        SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(db);
        mycon.Open();
        string query = "select Max(ANo + 1) AS AppointmentNO from tblApointment where ADate='"+TextBox1.Text +"' ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, mycon);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AppointmentNO"].ToString();
```

i am beginner help me if u can 
 this is the function MaxApointNo which i am calling on page load method
  textbox2 is area in which no will be shown on page load

Comment: when sysdate change textbox empty then i initialized it with zero in database then it start from 1. This is my problem. I just want that everday it start with one automatically

Answer (score 1):

as I can see this is about your query, you can manage it from your query, os this code snippet will be helpful

```
    // With Custom Parameter. pass textbox value in to date parameter
    //public int GetNextAppointmentNo(DateTime date)
    public int GetNextAppointmentNo()
    {
        string db = "Data Source=DESKTOP-R6H3RTP; Initial Catalog=TokenDB; Integrated Security=true; ";

        using (SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(db))
        {
            // this query is focused on Today
            string query = @"SELECT
                          COALESCE(MAX(ANo), 0) + 1 AS AppointmentNO
                        FROM tblApointment
                        WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ADate) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())";

            // With Custom Parameter

            //string query = @"SELECT
            //                COALESCE(MAX(ANo), 0) + 1 AS AppointmentNO
            //            FROM tblApointment
            //            WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ADate) = CONVERT(DATE, @ADate)";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, mycon))
            {
                // if you need to add custom parameter to the query
                // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADate", date);

                mycon.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    return reader.HasRows ? Convert.ToInt32(reader["AppointmentNO"].ToString()) : 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

anyway try to apply more **OOP concept** with **SOLID** Principle/s, and don't use inline query parameters, it will be focused your application into SQLInjection problems

Comment: and don't use your connections string in every place, isolate it as a global variable, or put it in the config file and read it from one place.

Answer (score 0):

on page load you can do this,

```
if( TextBox2.Text=="")
  TextBox2.Text="1";
```

by default the textbox value is 1,when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do postback every time then you can increment as below

> TextBox2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text) + 1).ToString();